# Just Bought a Ryzen 7 7700x Liq cooled,GeForce RTX 3070 8gb, 16gb RAM and 1TB ssd. Why all games Crashing with 3 32" Dell 1440 curved monitors

Tags: graphics-cards

I am brand new to the pc gaming world and don't understand hardly any of the lingo so bare with me. I've been using ps3/4 to play Sim Racing games for a decade now and figured it's time to upgrade, so I made the giant leap over to FanatecDDPro from the Logitech923 and went out and bought a pre-built liquid cooled gaming PC and 3 identical Dell 1440p 32" curved 165htz monitors from Best Buy. ($3,000 I know...) The PC has Ryzen 7 7700x, a Nvidia GeForce 3070 8gb GPU, 16gb ram, and 1tb ssd of storage space. That's it other than it's liquid cooled and has 5 fans, also it looks like a radiator between 2 of them. So I need to find out why it's continually going to "Black Screen"in the middle of the race and then either shutting down completely or requiring for me to do a Hardboot, I bought this thing because I was assured that it had MORE than enough power to run a triple screen setup. I'm not even worried about getting crazy fps or at a 4k resolution, I would settle in at a clean 1080p at 120htz. But I get some stupid "SplatBug" error message and it doesn't include any information as to what the error was, my GPU hasn't reached over 54°C since I bought it! So did I buy the wrong computer and what kind should I buy sticking to a budget of $1500 dollars.....   I'd appreciate any and all advice...

Comment: Sorry, this is tech support and this site is about buying new stuff. I would say post this on r/buildapc but they don't like prebuilts. I'm sorry I can't help you